# Deployment of node js app app engine google cloud "Forbidden" (403)

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

A little on-line board game made in js. Uses node express soket.io. after deployment in google cloud app engine i get 'Forbidden' in the deployed url.

Made some search, pretty scary ... just 'Forbidden' in Fire Fox. in Chrome too.

any ideas? besides listed in https://www.howtogeek.com/357785/what-is-a-403-forbidden-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/

the url:https://olgow-281316.ew.r.appspot.com/

Evrything works fine in localhost. and in the preview

Thank you all

olgow

Comment: HI, when I clicked on the application's URL and use Chrome's Developer Tool I get a `500 Internal Server Error message`. Please post a [minimum, reproduction example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of you code (including the app.yaml file) by removing all possible personal identifiable information. Also, regarding the initial `Forbidden (403)` error messages are you using any [Firewall configuration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/creating-firewalls) since these type of issues are usually linked to a bad Firewall configuration.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answer. Yes i get by the Forbiden (403) error now i got (500) Internel server  error.

Comment: Would you mind posting a [minimum, reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) version of your code (including the app.yaml to pursue a replication. As this will most likely mean there could be an error within the application.

Comment: app.yaml --->   runtime: nodejs10